# MFC WinApp calls InitInstance and OnAppExit/destructor in different threads

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, mfc

I got problem at one of our customers environment - when I AfxGetApp()->WriteProfileString in OnAppExit (or destructor) it doesn't work. I cannot reproduce it anywhere. I tracked it down that the OnAppExit is called from different thread than InitInstance - again, this isn't true at any of my machines.

Can it be the issue? And, why does the OnAppExit gets called in different thread? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OnAppExit` might get called on a different thread if you have threads in your app which generate an error and call `exit`. Under normal usage `OnAppExit` should only be called in your main thread. Here's the documentation for `exit` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9dcesdd.aspx.

Comment: Observed behavior (different thread for OnAppExit) occurs when user clicks 'exit' button (= calls message WM_COMMAND - ID_APP_EXIT)

Comment: That is most odd, are you sure the threads are different during CWinApp::OnInitInstance and CWinApp::OnExitInstance? Could it not be that WriteProfileString is failing for another reason? Have you debugged that function?

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of it being odd, that's why I'm asking here :-) I'm not able to run debugger on that machine, I dont control it :( And yes, I'm sure, I log in every of those function ID of thread it runs in.  WriteProfileString may fail form different reason. I'm not sure why -> this is only thing in logs that unusual for me.